# How to exchange the position of two objects in a ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a class called Player (with a lot of things on it).

And also, i have a ArrayList of Players with 20 players: `List<Player> Players = new ArrayList<Player>();`

for example, i want to exchange the player on the position 2 of the array with the player in the position 15 of the array.

Can someone give me the code to do this please? i don't know and i can't find the way on the documentation/google

thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try [Collections.swap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,%20int,%20int)):

```
Collections.swap(Players, 2, 15);
```